# Failure to discover property with reflection

Tags: reflection, f#

Taking the following minimal example:

```
type IMyInterface =
    interface
        abstract member Name: string with get
    end

let testInstance =
    { new IMyInterface with
        member _.Name = "Hello Word" }
```

I would have naively expected a call to `testInstance.GetType().GetProperties()` to contain a `PropertyInfo` element corresponding to `Name`.

However, only an empty array is returned.

Using `testInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Name")` yields no better as it simply returns a `<null>` object.

More confusing still, Visual Studio 2022 IntelliSense lists `Name` as a valid property (as I'd expect).

**How can I get a `PropertyInfo` corresponding to the `Name` property?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F# all interface implementations are private. This means that interface methods and properties do not appear as methods and properties of the implementing class.

In C# this works a bit differently: if you define a public member that happens to match an interface member, you don't have to explicitly tell the compiler that it's meant to be the interface implementation, the compiler will map it to the interface automatically for you.

So, for example, if you write this:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface {
  public string Name { get; }
}
```

The C# compiler will actually compile it as this:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface {
  public string Name { get; }
  string IMyInterface.Name { get { return this.Name; } }
}
```

(well, it's not *exactly* like that, but you get the idea)

But the F# compiler doesn't do that. If you want a class property in addition to the interface property, you have to roll one yourself:

```
type MyClass() =
  member __.Name = "Hello Word"
  interface IMyInterface with
    member this.Name = this.Name
```

But if you just want the interface property, you can get it off of the interface type:

```
let nameProp = typeof<IMyInterface>.GetProperty("Name")
let helloWorld = nameProp.GetValue testInstance
```

Or, if you don't know the interface type in advance, you can get it from the object type as well:

```
let intf = testInstance.GetType().GetInterfaces().[0]
let nameProp = intf.GetProperty("Name")
let helloWorld = nameProp.GetValue testInstance
```

Comment: Thanks Fyodor... I hadn't realised that the interface implementations were private. I have since searched for that phenomenon and it looks like others may have fallen foul of that. Also, thank you for clarifying how to obtain the `PropertyInfo` when the interface isn't known in advance which was another issue in my underlying project.

Comment: I don't know if private is the best term. In C#, an interface can implemented implicitly (by default) or explicitly (by qualifying each member with the interface name). This last is what is done in F# with a qualification that is done once for all members. Still, all the rest of the answer is really good.